# How to match only one group - Regex

Tags: regex

I am using Regex in the program Octoparse and I need to match only this `#67 in MIDI Controller` or this: `#30 in DJ Mixer`. I don't need the `#`, but I don't mind it. Since not every time it is going to end with `Controller` or `Mixer` I can't use the words as an end. 
Can I somehow group them and then choose which group to match? I know only basic Regex so it's a little bit hard for me. I saw I can use <\1> but it doesn't work.

[fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/a104wp/1)

Here is what the program looks like:
[image]

As you can see I can't remove the global flag.

Comment: So, what is wrong with your regex?

Comment: I need to match only one of the two at a time, not both.

Comment: Like https://regex101.com/r/a104wp/2 and https://regex101.com/r/a104wp/3?

Comment: Yes, but Octoparse doesn't allow me to remove the global flag like in your first fiddle. The second one is working perfectly - thank you.

Comment: And sometimes there are going to be 3 groups.

Comment: The second one only works when the match is the last thing on the page/document though.

Comment: Can I somehow group them and then choose which group to match? I know only basic Regex so it's a little bit hard for me. I saw I can use <\1> but it doesn't work.

Comment: I am not familiar with Octoparse, but isn't that driven by the Match All checkbox in the `Match with Regular Expression` dialog?

Comment: Octoparse is scraping data from websites. Since sometimes Amazon moves information in another list or table I have to adjust the XPath and then use Regex to look only for that sentence(if I can call it that way). The program always matches all - This is just their regex tool where I can test what happens. I click this checkbox so I can see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood from the description of your task, it doesn’t matter to you the first occurrence or the last, then you can do this:

```
(?!(.|\s)*?#\d+(.|\s)*?)(?<=#)(.+?)[\w\s].+
```

https://regex101.com/r/7OSJ7p/1

Comment: Actually it does matter. If I have this: `#67
    in MIDI Controller 
    #45
    in Woodwind Mouthpieces
    #30
    in DJ Mixer` How do I access the middle one?

Comment: So far, we have only managed to find a way to find the first match, but only if the total number of matches is known, if there are 3 of them, then the last part of the expression should be 3 - 1, that is `{2}`
[example](https://regex101.com/r/21Q7Ya/2)
RegEx:  `(?<=#[\w\W\s\S\d\D]+)((?<=#)(.+?)[\w\s].+)`
If I can write an expression that finds the middle element, I'll let you know